# Why is the Material UI's default theme not being stylized at all?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I've tried both Carbon Design for React (`@carbon/react`) and Material UI (`@mui/material`) with Next.js and the components are not stylized correctly. They work basically, but I noticed subtle and very notable issues. I decided to forget about IBM's Carbon and am noticing this with `@mui`:

- `CardHeader` is not showing
- Typography and button text colors are black, but I've specified the theme provider to use the dark mode.
- My Sig In button has `variant="contained"`, but its contained style does not apply.

This is the code:

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Box, Container, Card, CardHeader, CardContent, TextField, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
});

export default function Home() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<void>(undefined);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
        <Container>
          <Box>
            {auth == null ? <SigIn setAuth={setAuth}/> : null}
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

type SigInProps = {
  setAuth: (auth: void) => void,
};

function SigIn({setAuth}: SigInProps) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">Subtitle</Typography>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <TextField required id="username" label="Username"/>
          <TextField required id="password" type="password" label="Password" autoComplete="current-password"/>
          <Button variant="contained">Sig in</Button>
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Result:

[image: Picture]

I've posted the issue at GitHub also: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/38901

Answer (score 1):

The issue is [your implementation](https://github.com/hydroper/mui-theme-issue/blob/master/app/globals.css#L1) of [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) with [MUI](https://mui.com/).  Your app's usage of [Tailwind's CSS preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) style should be replaced with [CSSBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/). Tailwind `base` is adding styles that conflict with MUI. (For example, the button color.) You can [see the issue partly resolve when you comment out the first line](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/scarabaeus/mui-theme-issue/master?file=/app/globals.css:3,21&workspaceId=6a8de0e6-9e40-4542-be1a-5440e4c8d9a7) of your [globals.css](https://github.com/hydroper/mui-theme-issue/blob/master/app/globals.css#L1) file (`@tailwind base;`).

From the MUI [Tailwind CSS docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css):

> 1. Add Tailwind CSS to your project, following the instructions in
>    https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation.
> 2. Remove [Tailwind CSS's
>    preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) style so it can use the Material UI's preflight instead
>    ([CssBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/)).

From the sound if it, my assumption is that you had a similar issue with [Carbon](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/), but I haven't seen your implementation of that.